# Sequence of shifts in Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces

I'd like someone to check my work on this 2-part problem:

Let $(V_n )_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$  be a sequence of operators on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ defined by $(V_n x)(k) = x(n + k)$. Prove that $(V_n )_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in strong operator topology and identify its limit. Prove that the sequence of
adjoints $(V^*_n )_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge in the strong operator topology.

My approach:

Consider the limit of the square norm of the image:
$lim_{n\to \infty}||V_n x||^2 =lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=n}^\infty{x_k^2} = ||x||^2 - lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n{x_k^2} = 0$. Therefore $||V_nx|| \to 0$ for all $x$, and $V_n$ converges to $0$ in SOT.

For the second part, i'm quite sure that the adjoint of $V_n$ is $(V^*_nx)(k)= 0$ if $k\leq n$, and $(V^*x)(k)=x(k-n)$ otherwise. It is then enough to mention an $x$ for which the limit $V^*_nx$ does not exist. $x_0=1,0,0...$ will do, since the sequence $V^*_nx_0$ is not Cauchy and therefore not convergent. Therefore, $V_n^*$ does not converge in SOT.

any corrections and remarks are greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The notation $x(n+k)$ is very confusing (may be it is not from you ?). All seems correct otherwise. Good job !

Comment: Just my 2 cents, notation is more than  fine. In my opinion it is a disservice to students to hide for a long time that sequences are just functions with domain $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Fair point. However it is not very common. May be because it is easier to become messy ? -especially for function sequences-. So it is confusing (at least to me). @MartinArgerami

Comment: It is fairly common in my world. And it is not really confusing for sequences of functions, in my opinion; you would just be dealing with functions of two variables. Still, I agree that in that particular case using one subscript could help with notation. In fact it is commonly done in cases of functions of two variables where the variables have different roles (kernels come to mind).

Comment: @nicomezi , that's good to hear, thank you! notation is indeed not mine. though this being my first exposure and the only notation i've seen, i've already gotten used to it and it doesn't really confuse me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, your approach is correct. Well done!
I would like to point out that

> i'm quite sure that

does not sound good as a mathematical argument,
but the adjoint is correct.
Maybe you can cite a source for that claim
or briefly confirm that the adjoint is calculated correctly.

Also, the notation
$$x_0=1,0,0...$$
should be replaced with
$$x_0=(1,0,0...)$$
in my opinion.